# Internet speed slows to a crawl after certain point

Tags: networking, performance

I noticed that the internet speed for my company network is slowing down to unusable speeds every morning (less than 1 Mbps). At first I thought it was happening gradually, but I've now realized that it seems to be happening at a specific point of time. Restarting the Windows Server managing the network fixes the speed problem. We also have a Cisco router. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's hard to know why a Windows server would affect Internet performance unless it's also acting as a NAT gateway, router, firewall, or proxy. You may need to edit your question to add details of what your Windows server is set up to do on your network.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really not much to go on here.

What I have seen at a client (gradual, not the same time) was large video downloads (which were valid downloads). The client responded by permitting a higher speed pipe (at a greater cost).  That is one thing to consider.

Less likely, a rogue device attached to your network and also downloading stuff. Restarting the server would likely disconnect such devices at least temporarily.

Consider the above and then, if you can, add more detail about your network.